# List item doesn't correctly inserted

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem i want to create a list item using javascript. What i'm doing is first append a list item. After that insert new list item. But why it's not inserting items according to order.

```js
var refrenceNode = document.querySelector('#list');
    var newlistitem;
    var check = false;
    var o1 = {x: 1, y: 200, z: 500, a: 900};

    function extendSerialize(obj) {
        for (var property in obj) {
            if (!check) {
                newlistitem = refrenceNode.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
                newlistitem.innerHTML = obj[property];
                check = true;
            }
            else {
                newlistitem.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('li'), newlistitem.nextSibling).innerHTML = obj[property];
            }

        }
    }

    extendSerialize(o1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="list"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When iterating objects, with a `for/in` there is no guarantee that the properties will be iterated in any particular sequence. If that matters to you, you should use an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, this will do what you're trying to do. The insertBefore is causing you a possibly unnecessary headache.

```js
var referenceNode = document.querySelector('#list');
var o1 = {
  x: 1,
  y: 200,
  z: 500,
  a: 900
};

function extendSerialize(obj) {
  for (var property in obj) {
    var el = document.createElement("li");
    el.innerText = obj[property];
    referenceNode.appendChild(el);
  }
}

extendSerialize(o1);
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

I've taken your code and commented it, left it exactly as is otherwise:

```js
var refrenceNode = document.querySelector('#list');
var newlistitem;
var check = false;
var o1 = {
  x: 1,
  y: 200,
  z: 500,
  a: 900
};

function extendSerialize(obj) {
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (!check) {
      // As check is set to FALSE, we'll create an LI
      newlistitem = refrenceNode.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
      newlistitem.innerHTML = obj[property];
      check = true;
    } else {
    /****
     *  So here the check is true, we have a single LI,
     * and we want to use insertBefore. Here's a gotcha:
     * The first insertBefore the nextSibling will insert
     * AFTER the first list item. Every other LI will be
     * inserted BEFORE the SECOND LI, IN REVERSE ORDER.
     ****/
    newlistitem.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('li'), newlistitem.nextSibling).innerHTML = obj[property];
    }

  }
}

extendSerialize(o1);
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of properties on an object is not guaranteed, you should use an Array.  Something like this may work, if you need the property names you could use an array of small objects

```
var refrenceNode = document.querySelector('#list');
var newlistitem;
var check = false;
var o1 = [1, 200, 500, 900];

function extendSerialize(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var item = arr[i];
        if (!check) {
            newlistitem = refrenceNode.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
            newlistitem.innerHTML = item;
            check = true;
        }
        else {
            newlistitem.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('li'), newlistitem.nextSibling).innerHTML = item;
        }

    }
}

extendSerialize(o1);
```